# by overloading [], how to assign values to the second array member in a class?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, operator-overloading, member-functions

I am a learner. I am working on operator overloading. I am writing a code that has the below items:
1. A class with two member arrays
2. Overloaded [] function
If my class has just one array member, I can overloaded [] to assign the values. But what can I do assign the values to the second member array. Here is my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
class Digit
{
private:
    int digit1[3]{0};
    int digit2[4]{0};

public:    
    int& operator[](const int index);

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& out);
};

int& Digit::operator[](const int index)
{
    return digit1[index];
}

ostream& Digit::operator<<(ostream& out)
{
    int loop;
    out << "{";
    for (loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++)
    {
        out << digit1[loop] << " ";
    }
    out << "}";

    return o;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    Digit n;
    n[0] = 4;
    n[1] = 3;
    n[2] = 4;


    n << cout;

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, how can I overloaded [] to assign values for digit2[4]?

Answer (score 1):

`operator[]` is your own function; you can re-interpret the index in whatever way that you wish - it's a simple parameter.

For example, you could say that indexes 0..2 address `digit1`, while indexes 3 and above address `digit2`:

```
int& Digit::operator[](const int index)
{
    return index < 3 ? digit1[index] : digit2[index];
}
```

This is only one possible way of interpreting `index`. You could say that positive numbers are indexes into `digit1`, and negative numbers are indexes into `digit2`:

```
int& Digit::operator[](const int index)
{
    return index >= 0 ? digit1[index] : digit2[-index];
}
```

Comment: That is one way that works if there are two member arrays. What if it has 3 or more member arrays?

Comment: @KiranCK Make a chain of `if`/`else`s to do the same for many arrays.